# What is the meaning of flatmap( return Observer::onComplete;) in rxJava? And why is the return type of it is Observerable<POJO>?

Tags: java, android, rx-java

```java
Observable<POJO> localRequest = Database.getInstance(this.context).getAllQuestions().flatMapObservable((questions) -> {
         ContentHolder.getHolder().setQuestionMap(questions);
         return Observer::onComplete;
     });

 public Maybe<Question[]> getAllQuestions () {
     
 }
```

I cannot understand the line of return Observer::onComplete;

Comment: That line makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a fancy and incorrect way of doing an empty result á la `Observable.empty()`.

`fatMapObservable` expects an `Observable<POJO>` as its return due to target typing. Since `Observable` is a single abstract method type, you can use a lambda expression to construct an instance of it. I.e., have the `subscribe(Observer<POJO>)` method implemented via `observer -> observer.onComplete()` or `Observer::onComplete`.